# Integrating online payment in app or website using UPI

Tags: flutter, payment, razorpay, upi

I am trying to find an online solution for a multi-vendor application. In this application, there will be multiple vendors and multiple customers and I want to add a feature for vendors to collect payment on their UPI id from customers.

I am thinking that the vendor will give us their VPA of UPI id and I will save that VPA address directly in the database when the customer will try to pay that vendor I will retrieve VPA from the database and make a payment to that vendor.

I tried razor pay, cash-free, PayU, Paytm SDK but no one has the solution. earlier I used this library https://pub.dev/packages/upi_india but it is not working now.

There is one solution I found
https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/otherapis/omnichannel/initiate-payment
But for this user's have to have google pay installed on their phone

and one other solution is Razorpay routes
https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/route/ But I don't want to integrate this because for using this feature we need the vendor's bank account details and I don't want to collect bank account detail from the vendor.

Any answers or links to this solution are very much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I didn't find any solution. I am using Razorpay routes for now.